# TCP Retransmission after Reset RST flag

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, wireshark

I have around 20 clients communicating together with a central server in the same LAN. The clients can make transaction simultaneously with the server. The server forward each transaction to external appliance in the network. Sometimes it works, sometimes my application shows a "time out" message in a client screen (randomly)

I mirrored all traffic and found TCP Retransmission after TCP Reset packets for the first TCP Sequence. I immediately thought about packet loss but all my cables/NIC are fine, and I do not see DUP ACK in the capture.

It seems that RST packets may have different significations.
**What causes those TCP Reset?

Where should I focus my investigation: network or application design ?**

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: An RST might happen, if your client sends data which the server does not read before closing the connection. E.g. this might be an attempt to build a HTTP server which does not read the request from the client but only sends some data immediately after connect from the client and then closes the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the capture, I assume your central server is `137.56.64.31`. What's happening is the clients are initiating a connection to the server with a `SYN` packet and the server responds with a `RST`. This is typical if the server has no application listening on that particular port e.g. the webserver application isn't running and a client tries to connect to port 80.

The clients are all connecting to different ports on the server, which is unusual for an central server, but not unheard of. The destination ports the clients are connecting to on the server are: `11007, 11012, 11014, 11108, and 11115`. Is that normal for the application? If not, the clients should be connecting to whatever port the application server is listening on.

The reason for the retransmits is that instead of giving up on the connection upon receiving a `RST` from the server, the client tries to initiate the connection again so Wireshark considers it a retransmission.